# SVG library for C++ for creating interactive svg files

Tags: c++, scripting, svg, libraries, interactive

Is there a simple lib that I can use to create interactive svg with C++? I've found this one: [simple-svg](https://code.google.com/p/simple-svg/) ,  but I can't add `<script>` tag, or `<set>` tag to elements. In Python I've successfully used [SVGFig](https://code.google.com/p/svgfig/),  but I'm beginner with C++, so any help would be appreciated.

For example, I need to be able to create something like this (use of `xlink:href` is very important to me):

```
<script type="text/ecmascript">  ... function SetTooltip(Id) ... </script>
<text id="tooltip" font-size="3" visibility="hidden" y="5" x="75" fill="black"> </text>
<defs>
    <g id="groupOne"> ... some elements ... </g>
    <g id="groupTwo"> ... some elements ... </g>
</defs>
<use id="gid" xlink:href="#groupOne" y="10" x="20" onmouseover="SetTooltip("gid")">
    <set attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0.5"  begin="mouseover" end="mouseout"/>
    <set xlink:href="#tooltip" attributeName="visibility" from="hidden" to="visible" begin="gid.mouseover" end="gid.mouseout" />
</use>
```